# Using a Java Applet in CiviCRM Extension

Tags: extension

Does anyone have any idea how to get a Java Applet to work in a CiviCRM Extension? In particular, I'm trying to load the QZ-Print applet.

The first problem I'm having is getting the location of the jar. Currently the code to embed the applet is (where the applet is in www/qz-print/ dir on the localhost):

```
<applet id="qz" name="QZ Print Plugin" code="qz.PrintApplet.class" archive="/qz-print/qz-print.jar" width="100" height="100"></applet>
```

The code is in the main page TPL file for my extension. This seems to (sometimes) completely hang the web page/browser... On the occasion where it does load the page, I get the following: "SecurityException JAR should not contain JNLP-INF/APPLICATION.JNLP".

Anyways, I'm at a loss for what to do right now. Any help on getting an applet to work with an extension would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
So I looked into this and realized that I need to load the JNLP file. So I'm doing that now. HOWEVER, I'm having trouble getting the path to the jnlp/jar file. When working with an extension paths aren't typical.

How does one go about getting the path to the JAR/JNLP within an extension?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the archive path is incorrect.
You can make it an absolute path by assigning it to the template from php:

```
$path = CRM_Extension_System::singleton()->getMapper()->keyToBasePath('myextension');
$this->assign('basePath', $path);
```

Your archive url can then begin with the smarty variable `{$basePath}`

Comment: Coleman, thanks. I was able to use this to get the path that I needed. I was finally able to get qzprint working and now I am able to print barcodes/labels from my extension!